# spark sql add comment with withComment, it is not work

Tags: apache-spark

I want to add remarks to the dataframe, then write hive table,but it is not work.That is to say, the remarks of the table are not added.

I try in spark 2.4 and spark 3, it is not work. But the lower version seems to work, I don't know why,I tried to read the source code but found nothing, if you know why, please tell me, thank you

The code as follows

```scala
val personRDD: RDD[Row] = GetTestRDD.map((line: String) => {
  val arr: Array[String] = line.split(" ")
  Row(arr(0).toInt, arr(1), arr(2).toInt)
})
val schema: StructType = StructType(List(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, nullable = false),
  StructField("name", StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = false)
))
val frame: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(personRDD, schema)
println("输出原始信息")
frame.schema.foreach((s: StructField) => println(s.name, s.metadata))

//添加备注后处理
val commentMap: Map[String, String] = Map("id" -> "唯一标识", "name" -> "姓名", "age" -> "年龄")
val newSchema: Seq[StructField] = frame.schema.map((s: StructField) => {
  println(commentMap(s.name))
  s.withComment(commentMap(s.name))
})
sparkSession.createDataFrame(frame.rdd, StructType(newSchema)).repartition(10)
println("输出处理后的信息")
frame.schema.foreach((s: StructField) => println(s.name, s.metadata))
```

the output

```
输出原始信息
    (id,{})
    (name,{})
    (age,{})
    输出处理后的信息
    (id,{})
    (name,{})
    (age,{})
```

Comment: update!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: update!!!!!!!!!!